# how to handle a custom url event?

Tags: android, parsing, android-intent, android-activity, webview

I am having a problem with my app crashing when I click my "add to calendar" button, Looking at logcat i found that I have no activity to handle the event, I am not quite sure how to work this that that when the button is pressed it parse's the information from the url with this code

```
package com.sideresult.cyfaircal;

public class Event {
String[] myStringArr;

int day;
int month;
int year;
String timeString;
int hourS;
int minuteS;
int hourE;
int minuteE;
String title;
String timezone;

public int getDay() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[0].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMonth() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[1].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getYear() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[2].split("=")[1]);
}

public String getTimeString() {
    return myStringArr[3].split("=")[1];
}

public int getHourS() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[4].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMinuteS() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[5].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getHourE() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[6].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMinuteE() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[7].split("=")[1]);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return myStringArr[8].split("=")[1];
}

public String getTimezone() {
    return myStringArr[9].split("=")[1];
}

public Event(String[] myStringArr) {
    super();
    this.myStringArr = myStringArr;
}
}
```

currently the whole app runs in a webview, all of my handles for that are in this code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("filenecal.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what kind of activity i would need in order to parse and add the parsed data to a calendar from a custom url like so

> mlevents://add/event?day=8&month=10&year=2014&timestring=12:00 PM - 12:30 PM &hourS=12&minuteS=00&hourE=12&minuteE=30&title=Filene 101: Think. Do. Change. | Webinar&timezone=CST

and here is my logcat [image: logcat]

here is my tab2 with the calendar

```
package com.sideresult.cyfaircal;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Tab2 extends Activity {



private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://filenecal.com/mobile/index.php");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
     WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyAppWebViewClient with in any activity ?? if not, then you need to first create an activity and then you need to have the object of your MyAppWebViewClient class inside that Activity which serves as the main activity for your application.

then you can simply call

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

instead of

```
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method.

You can invoke this webviewclient from the oncreate method from your activity as shown below

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if see any issues.

Comment: i am indeed using that in an activity, it is in my tab2 which is where the calendar is loaded, but when i click the button add to calendar it doesnt know what to do with the mlevent

Comment: i have made an edit to the question showing where i call MyAppWebViewClient, the question is how can i get it to hand the mlevent inside of webview on tab two, I am unsure of the code to use to get it to then parse the info and export it to calendar instead of crashing the app